# Java Annotation and Processor to mark a method as so it can be called once and only once?

Tags: java, annotations, jaxb, dynamic-proxy, cglib

I need to be able to mark methods so that they throw a RuntimeException if they are called more than once.

I am trying to enforce some single assignment semantics and the number of parameters to my class is too large to put in a single constructor and I need to be able to make these classes `JAXB` aware as well, so the objects need to be mutable but I want to enforce single assignment semantics.

I am pretty sure I can do this with Aspects, but I would really like to be able to use my own Annotations processor instead.

I know how to do this with Decorators in Python.

**How do I write an Annotation processor that can intercept calls to the annotated method at runtime and not just at compile time?**

I think I am on to something with with Dynamic Proxies intercepting the method calls, I just need to figure out how to integrate them with my Annotation processor.

Dynamic Proxies require you to use an Interface, that is way to cumbersome, I have a [CGLib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) [MethodInterceptor](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/cglib/proxy/MethodInterceptor.html) working now, much less requirements on what gets intercepted and decorated, at the expense of adding a dependency.

Comment: An annotation doesn't have any behaviour. It's just metadata, that is intended to be used by some tool or framework. You could have an aspect that looks for the presence of an annotation and does what you want, but an annotation alone won't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there's nothing ready-to-use. And AspectJ seems the only way to make it work in a more general manner. As JB Nizet noted - the annotation should have a parser to parse it.

However, I would advise for a better and simpler solution - the Builder pattern. What does it look like:

- you have a `FooBuilder` (it may also be a static inner class) which is mutable and has a setter and getter for each of the fields
- `FooBuilder` has a `build()` method that returns an instance of `Foo`
- `Foo` has a constructor that takes only `FooBuilder`, and you assign each field there.

That way:

- `Foo` is immutable, which is your end goal
- It is easy to use. You only set the fields that you need. Something like:

  ```
  Foo foo = new Foo.FooBuilder().setBar(..).setBaz(..).build();
  ```

That way the builder can be JAXB-aware. For example:

```
FooBuilder builder = (FooBuilder) unmarshaller.unmarshal(stream);
Foo foo = builder.build();
```

JAXB objects need to be mutable, and your requirement is an immutable object. Hence the builder comes handy to bridge that.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson see my last paragraph that I just added

Comment: Wow, I think that might be exactly what I need for a certain project!

Comment: @Bozho, I tend to bypass builder stuff, add a flag "configured" and assertConfigurable() on the mutators. Later if a mutator needs to be enabled (say JMX), just remove the assertion. Builder pattern duplicates just looks cumbersome at least.

Answer (score 2):

This question shows some resemblance with question [Applying CGLib Proxy from a Annotation Processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984108/applying-cglib-proxy-from-a-annotation-processor).

If you want to be able to change the behavior of the original source code in an annotation processor have a look at how http://projectlombok.org/ achieves this. The only downside IMO is that lombok relies on com.sun.* classes.

Since I need this kind of stuff myself I wonder if someone knows of a better way to achieve this, still using annotation processors.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure JAXB to use field (instance variable) access using `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.  This will allow you to do what you need to with the set method:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

You can also use JAXB's `XmlAdapter` mechanism to support immutable objects:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an annotation you can use.

```
assert count++ != 0;
```

You would need one counter per method.

Comment: Having to check a method is called once at runtime is a nasty requirement.

Comment: I approve the assertion approach, always makes me wonder why people expect too much from 'frameworks' when there is an extra simple solution (and doesn't require learning any funky stuff)

Comment: @bestsss, You can bring me up to 0 if you like.

Comment: @Peter, ... but i never vote, if none does it i can grant 50 bounty i guess, though

Comment: I do think assertions are disabled at runtime, though. I once used some and was surprised to see they let wrong things pass until I was reminded they're not on by default. Your approach could make just throw a simple runtime exception, like IllegalStateException.

Comment: @G_H, `java -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]` (or `-ea`), by default of course they are disabled

Comment: @bestsss That'd work, assuming he's got control over where and how the code is used. That might not be the case. Also, assertions are brilliant for checking if code is working as expected, but in this case it's more a matter of whether the code is used properly, i.e. the method only called once. So I believe throwing a runtime exception and letting whatever's (ab)using your code deal with it is acceptable. Then again, that's practically what assertions do... Anyway, +1 because it's actually a decent suggestion.

Comment: @G_H, assertions have the benefit of zero runtime cost due to constant folding optimization...

Comment: @bestsss Interesting, didn't know that! I was gonna say that such minor optimizations shouldn't play a role in design decisions... But then who knows how many methods he'd apply this on.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement. Long story short when you inject components in Spring the cyclic dependency situation like A depends on B and B depends on A is perfectly fine, but you need to inject these components as fields or setters. Constructor injection causes a stack overflow. Therefore I had to introduce a method `init()` for these components, which unlike constructors might be *erroneously* called more than once. Needless to say boilerplate code like:

```
private volatile boolean wasInit = false;
public void init() {
  if (wasInit) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Method has already been called");
  }
  wasInit = true;
  logger.fine("ENTRY");
  ...
}
```

started to emerge everywhere. Since this is nowhere close to being a critical spot of the application, I made a decision to introduce an elegant thread-safe *one-liner solution* favoring conciseness over speed:

```
public class Guard {
  private static final Map<String, Object> callersByMethods = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
  
  public static void requireCalledOnce(Object source) {
    StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
    String fullClassName = stackTrace[1].getClassName();
    String methodName = stackTrace[1].getMethodName();
    int lineNumber = stackTrace[1].getLineNumber();
    int hashCode = source.hashCode();
    // Builds a key using full class name, method name and line number
    String key = new StringBuilder().append(fullClassName).append(' ').append(methodName).append(' ').append(lineNumber).toString();
    System.out.println(key);

    if (callersByMethods.put(key, source) != null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("%s@%d.%s() was called the second time.", fullClassName, hashCode, methodName));
    }
  }
}
```

Now, since I prefer building applications within DI frameworks it might sound natural to declare `Guard` as a component, then inject it, and call an instance method `requireCalledOnce` instead. But due to its universal flavor, static reference yields more sense. Now my code looks like this:

```
private void init() {
  Guard.requireCalledOnce(this);
  ...
}
```

and here is an exception upon the second invocation of `init` of the same object:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: my.package.MyComponent@4121506.init() was called the second time.
    at my.package.Guard.requireCalledOnce(Guard.java:20)
    at my.package.MyComponent.init(MyComponent.java:232)
    at my.package.MyComponent.launch(MyComponent.java:238)
    at my.package.MyComponent.main(MyComponent.java:48)
```